# How do I search for a word in a text document and display that line?

Tags: python, search, text

this is what i have at the moment. i need some help. im new to python and dont have that much knowledge on it. i need to search the file for a certain word word and then when the word occurs in the line it prints it.

```
file = open(input("please input your file name   "))
        word = input("please enter the value you want to search for   ")

    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if 'word' in line:
                print (line)
```

the problem im having is understanding what i need to assign to the with statement. to find the word and the line. at the moment i have file as file in the with statement. i do not know what else to put.

Comment: Please explain exactly what the issue with your code is. What is the problem and what attempts have been made to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be (note that there are no quotes):

```
if word in line:
```

not

```
if 'searchphrase' in line:
```

Comment: I guess you're right... but this could have been an error when copying the code into the site.